# Problemas com SelectedIndexChanged asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Adicionei no método onde carrega a lista vinda do banco:

```
ddlSalas.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("TODAS", ""));
```

Quando escolho essa opção "TODAS" no `dropdownlist`, acontece um post na página mas ele não chama o evento `selectedindexchanged` que contém o método que irá carregar uma `gridview` com as informações.

O que pode estar acontecendo? O que fiz de errado ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qual é o dado inicial do combo ? já é o **Todas** ?
Que tal usar um ddlSalas.Items.Insert(-1, new ListItem("Selecione", "")); antes do ddlSalas.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("TODAS", "")); ? Será que dá certo ?

Comment: eu consegui resolver isso. Obrigado.

Comment: seria legal você postar a solução para todos saberem como resolver !

Comment: Eu estava fazendo errado, estava passando vazio e ele não caia nem no breakpoint, ai a solução foi atribuir um valor "0" e mudar a query na procedure para que retornasse os registros de acordo com a passagem "0"

ddlSalas.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("TODAS", "0"));

Answer (score 2):

Bem estranho cara, era pra funcionar, se o generated do seu arquivo gerou corretamente a atribuição do evento para seu dropdownlist, mas beleza, pra garantir que seu método seja chamado, tente colocar depois de adicionar os itens na lista esse comando:

```
dropdownlist.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(dropdownlist_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Comment: Mesma coisa @Thiago Falcão, ao executar, escolho a opção e acontece um post na página mas não retorna nada e nem chama o breakpoint. Ai quando seleciono outro (que no caso está retornando do banco) funciona, e depois que escolhi uma opção que funcionou, volto nela e funciona.

Comment: @AndreeH po cara, acho que ele deva estar se perdendo no índice então, parece que esse primeiro valor está com índice negativo, tente ver o indice quando você seleciona os outros itens que entra no evento, mais  ou menos assim você vai saber em qual índice está:

switch (dropdownlist.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 1:  // ..... some code here...
            break;
        case 2:  // ..... some code here...
            break;
        case 3:  // ..... some code here...
            break;
        default: // ..... some code here...
            break;
    }

Comment: Beleza @Thiago Falcão. Vou tentar.